# Embeding multiple apps in an app?

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile

I am a newcomer to application development and I'm wondering if the concept I have can actually be created.

My concept involves creating an app that has the ability to embed another app within itself.

I'll do an example which is also a very bad one but you'll at least get the point.

Picture an app on the iphone that's called "Kwesi's app". Once you tap on it, it opens up a page with 3 icons. A facebook icon, a gmail icon and a hotmail icon. Now tap your finger on the gmail icon and instantly your gmail opens up withing "Kwesi's app" and you have full access. There is also a button in the top left corner that says "Main Menu". Once you tap the "Main Menu" icon, you go back to the three icons and can now rinse and repeat.

I hope this example is clear enough.

The question I seem to be coming back to is, would it be possible having an application that embeds or links you to other apps in that manner? I can only guess that it'd be really weird since they'd have to be installed seperately on your phone but I don't want that. I want one app that can handle an already set amount of apps within itself as the above example shows.

Thank you very much for reading and any thought would be very much appreciated.

/Kwesi

Comment: I do not think so. All you can do is, have a document open in another app. For example, if you have an app with documents of type .pdf, then you can make the document open in other apps which can handle pdfs. But just having icons and then opening other apps is not possible. However, if you have a webview and you have custom protocols defined, you can achieve some of what you have said.

Comment: See Google's iPhone app for an example of what Srikanth is suggesting. You absolutely cannot embed other people's apps within yours, and can only "embed" your own as much as you can put all the functionality into a single app.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible in iOS for security reasons. But you have the following choices to modify your idea:

- [Register a protocol for the app](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLProtocol_Class/Reference/Reference.html) : This will allow you to send data between applications using protocols. However, if the app wasn't made by you and doesn't have a protocol, then you can't use it.
  Using this idea, it is possible to open an application. For example, opening Facebook with "fb://" or evernote with "evernote://". I am sure there are other applications that have these protocols. Just be aware that you don't have control on the application in this case. You can only open it and send data to it.
- Since your example was about Facebook, Gmail. Then I would suggest using their corresponding API and build everything in your application. Many famous applications provide APIs for a fee or free usage. You have to check with each one separately.

Comment: Thank you very much for the replies. I believe you've given me the answers I was looking for. Will come for more feedback should any other questionmarks errupt.

Peace!
/Kwesi

Comment: I am glad that the reply is sufficient for you. You can mark the answer as correct, so the question is considered as answered.